# Groovy: Date clearTime() question

Tags: groovy

So why does this work:

```
requestInstance.needByDate = new Date() + 4
requestInstance.needByDate.clearTime()
```

But this doesn't ?

```
requestInstance.needByDate= (new Date() + 4).clearTime()
```

**EDIT**: as indicated below by Tim this is a bug in Groovy version: 1.7.9-SNAPSHOT (the one I am using of course)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't get it to not work...

```
needByDate = new Date() + 4
needByDate.clearTime()
println needByDate

needByDate = (new Date() + 4).clearTime()
println needByDate
```

Run with Groovy 1.8 prints:

```
Fri Jul 22 00:00:00 UTC 2011
Fri Jul 22 00:00:00 UTC 2011
```

What version of Groovy are you running?  Maybe a previous version did not have `clearTime` returning a `Date`?

***Edit***

Yeah, found it.  [There was a bug reported](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4788) that `clearTime()` should return a `Date` and it was fixed in Groovy 1.8.0 and 1.7.11

Comment: I am using Groovy version: 1.7.9-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Thanks Tim ... that's an odd one :)

Comment: @DmitryB It sometimes happens.  Features get added, and then improved later on when someone else spots things that could be better :-)  Glad I could help tho :-)